# problem to export to a csv file with a loop

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a python program where I have to export all the data from a csv file line by line. I managed to extract the data and make the loop. but I can't manage to export the processed data (coordinates) on another csv file. here is the code and an extract of the csv file I have. would you have a solution and/or improvements :)

ps: i know it's really not clean only god knows how it works

Pyton :

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import geocoder
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

f = open('Data-nom.csv', 'r')
NumberOfLine = 0
for line in f:
    NumberOfLine += 1
print('Nombre de lignes: ',NumberOfLine)
e = 0
d = 0
while d < 20464 :
    e += 1
    with open('Data-nom.csv', 'r') as file:
        val = list(csv.reader(file))[e]
        print(val)
        x = val
        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="test")
        location = geolocator.geocode(x)
    print(location.address)
    latlong = (location.latitude, location.longitude)
    print(latlong)
    with open('out.csv', 'w', newline = '') as csvfile:
        my_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ' ')
        my_writer.writerow(latlong)
    d += 1
```

CSV :

```
2 RUE FLAMENG CLERMONT FERRAND 63000
12 CITE DE LA MONTADE AURILLAC 15000
37 BOULEVARD JOSEPH ROSSELLI BELLEVILLE 69220
1 AVENUE DE LA RESISTANCE MONTREUIL 93100
AVENUE DE LINGENFELD TORCY 77200
70 RUE LEON FROT PARIS 75011
```

Comment: The indentation of your code is broken. You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71847230/edit) the question to fix it ;)

Comment: Drop the CSV library and just use pandas. That will be a lot easier to use.

Comment: thanks, i already try with just pandas and i can't solve how to get line by line

Comment: Please describe to is IN WORDS what you believe this code is doing.  What's the purpose?  You shouldn't be reading your CSV file in a loop like that.  And that's not a CSV file.  It's just a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Open the files once; read/process each line of the input file, then write that processed data to the output file...

algorithm/pseudocode

```
with open('Data-nom.csv', 'r') as file, open('out.csv', 'w', newline = '') as csvfile:
   for each line in file:
       # get the lat and lon from the line
       # write the lat,lon to the csvfile
```

Comment: when i run my code i have this output 
``` 
['2 RUE FLAMENG  CLERMONT FERRAND  63000']
Rue Flameng, Saint-Jacques, Clermont-Ferrand, Puy-de-Dôme, Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes, France métropolitaine, 63000, France
(45.757172, 3.0966988)
```

and on the out.csv i have the coordinates that I need

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you want, more sensibly, with no pandas and no CSV.  Neither of your files are CSV files.  They're just text files.

```
import geocoder
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

outfile = open('out.csv', 'w')
for row in open('Data-nom.csv'):
    location = geolocator.geocode(row)
    print(location.address)
    latlong = (location.latitude, location.longitude)
    print( f"{location.latitude} {location.longitude}", file=outfile)
```

Comment: thanks, the files a to big (+20000 lines)

Comment: That isn't necessarily too big.  Did you try it?  Although, with this organization, there's no need to read it all into memory.  I've changed it to go file-to-file directly.